# How to add dates to alarm manager in android

Tags: android, calendar, date, alarmmanager

I have a two dates for example `17/3/2012` and `18/3/2012` and I want to set these dates in alarm manager . how to use calendar instance to add them?

Comment: What do you mean by adding dates to alarm? You mean, you want to set an alarm to only set off on a single set date at a single set time?

Comment: I want to set alarm to different times,

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Calendar` class and its `set()` method. It takes two parameters: a `Calendar` field, such as `YEAR`, `MONTH`, `HOUR_OF_DAY`, and the value of the field. You must initialize the `Calendar` object, setting all the fields as you need, and then call `getTimeInMillis()` to get the time in milliseconds. Here's a link to the `Calendar` reference: [Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html). Hope this helps.